# Как защитить от ботов форму регистрации на сайте?

Tags: wordpress, безопасность

Есть WordPress-сайт, на котором логика продаж требует регистрации пользователей. Есть страница с кастомной формой регистрации.

Идёт непрерывный поток спам-ботов, которые регистрируются на сайте.

Форма регистрации выглядит примерно так:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="password1">
<input type="text" name="password2">
... дополнительные поля информации пользователя
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" required>

<input type="checkbox" name="site_remember_me">
<input type="hidden" name="reg_nonce_field" value="значение">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Чекбокс terms пользователь должен отметить, чтобы принять правила. Заполненность всех полей проверяется на стороне сервера.

Для борьбы с ботами в форму были введены дополнительные поля ввода:

1. Чекбокс `site_remember_me`, который представляет из себя классический honeypot. Скрыт посредством css, человек его отметить не может. На сервере проверяется: если отмечен, значит, бот.
2. Стандарное поле nonce, генерируемое функцией WordPress

   wp_nonce_field( 'verify_reg', 'reg_nonce_field' );

Результат - боты пролазят всё равно. Простой POST-запрос на страницу с другого сайта не проходит из-за nonce. Посредством экспериментов и логирования выяснено, что бот считывает страницу, находит форму, использует nonce в поле ввода `reg_nonce_field`, и отправляет форму.

При этом - прошу обратить внимание - интеллектуально проставляет чекбоксы: включает `terms` и не трогает honeypot `site_remember_me`. Вероятность того, что он читает файлы css, низка - их много, и надо найти, что чекбокс `site_remember_me` скрыт. Скорее всего, бот использует что-то вроде phantom.js, чтобы получить полное дерево DOM со стилями всех элементов, и отсекает те, что невидимы на экране.

**Вывод**. Против современных ботов honeypot и nonce не помогают.

**Вопрос**. А что же делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку выше перечисленные меры не помогли, был установлен плагин [Invisible reCaptcha for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/invisible-recaptcha/). Он эффективно отсекает ботов на стандартных страницах регистрации, входа, забытого пароля, комментариев. Но на кастомной странице регистрации ситуация не изменилась до тех пор, пока не было сделано две вещи:

Внутрь кода php генерации формы вставлена строка

```
<?php do_action( 'google_invre_render_widget_action' ); ?>
```

В проверки полученных из формы данных добавлен код проверки

```
// Verify invisible recaptcha.
$is_valid = apply_filters( 'google_invre_is_valid_request_filter', true );
if ( ! $is_valid ) {
    die();
}
```

Применение этих мер полностью остановило поток регистрации ботов.

**Вывод**. Для борьбы с современными ботами полагаться на honeypot не стоит. Чтобы надёжно защитить любые формы ввода, стоит использовать инструмент, разработанный Google - невидимую рекапчу.

Comment: «надёжно» — ну... как минимум сомнительно) https://habr.com/company/pentestit/blog/341322/

Comment: @andreymal Это статья про обход recaptcha v2

Comment: А есть какая-то принципиальная разница? В Invisible Recaptcha есть такая же аудиокапча

Comment: Мы не знаем, какие усовершенствования сделал Гугл при работе над Invisible Recaptcha. Пока не появится статья, что unCaptcha пробивает Invisible Recaptcha, можно только гадать. Боты на том сайте, о котором я пишу, не справились с новым барьером защиты. И да - а какие есть более надёжные варианты?

Comment: А нету их, в самом крайнем случае будет толпа китайцев, решающих капчи за еду) Но замечу, что от простых ботов хорошо помогает и обыкновеннейшая картинка с текстом

Comment: Судя по изложенному в вопросе - это не сильно простой бот.

Comment: Ну собственно вы сами про phantomjs в вопросе упомянули, так что ничего удивительного) А вот против (любой) капчи phantomjs уже не поможет (кстати, есть люди, которые жалуются, что они лучше уж слово с картинки введут, чем будут пять минут прокликивать гугловские знаки да автомобили, потому что гугл посчитал их роботами) (впрочем, это уже совсем оффтопик)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79223/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-andreymal).

Comment: Вот гуглокапча https://i.imgur.com/Wy1XZ0D.jpg и это  https://i.imgur.com/LBif6Pp.jpg из [разговоров в слаке](https://ruwp.slack.com/archives/C1FSEU4DP/p1524503057000917). Юзайте-юзайте, если не юзеры не интересуют.

Answer (score 1):

> Вывод. Против современных ботов honeypot и nonce не помогают.

Вывод не верный. Помогает в большинстве случаев. Просто нужно подходить с умом и персонально.

> Чтобы надёжно защитить любые формы ввода, стоит использовать
>   инструмент, разработанный Google - невидимую рекапчу.

Если интересуют люди - не стоит использовать никакие капчи, в уж от гугла и подавно. Никакая он не инвизибл, ограничивает юзеров по  массе параметров + собирает данные.
Да и "надёжно" - это не так. Пробивается сервисамми антикапчи только так.

А кроме капчи и скрытых полей есть ещё много др способов защиты от автоспама.

Даже акисмет и тот справляется относительно не плохо.

А ида. Капча - зло. И своеобразная "метка": вебмастер - ленив, неграмотен, криворук раз не способен защититься от спама нормальными средствами.

Comment: Ну, насчет ленивого вебмастера это ты вебмастерам Гулга скажи, им понравится. А в моем случае какой конкретный совет можешь дать  - как бороться с этим ботом без капчи, с умом и персонально?

Comment: У них другие цели - сбор данных. И они успешно из решают за счёт  неучей.То капчами, то httpSами..

Comment: А твоего случая я не вижу. Да и если бы видел - нужнен анализ, если тебе персонально долбят умными ботами.

Comment: @KAGGDesign в общем ты свою персональную проблему вывел как общую и ещё и "панацею" прилепил.. Это неправильно. Удали бы ты этот вопрос.

Comment: Твоя неприязнь к капчам известна давно. Но пока что, кроме пустых разговоров, я ничего не вижу. В вопросе конкретная проблема. Описана форма. Бот обходит honeypot. Какие у тебя предложения? Я попробую.

Comment: Согласен с SeVlad. На перспективных ресурсах, капчу желательно использовать в самом крайнем случае: много запросов с одного ip, подозрительный user-agent, прямой переход к форме. Все данные от "новых пользователей" можно помечать как "требующие проверки" и тд и тп. Но если сайт временный, то думаю с этим не стоит заморачиваться, проще сразу поставить капчу.

Comment: @KAGGDesign да причем тут код формы в вопросе. Нужно анализировать работу бота и ставить разные эксперименты, если реально так тяжко. А то может достаточно его по IP/UA/етс забанить.

Comment: Я это уже делал - если ты внимательно прочитаешь вопрос, увидишь. По IP не забанить - каждый раз новый подсовывал. Чекбоксы ставил интеллектуально. Honeypot обходил. Раньше простой генератор капчи на php стоял на сайте - толку ноль, я его убрал. Что ещё придумать?