# SMS регистрация и авторизация

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, сессия, sms

Необходимо реализовать на сайте регистрацию и авторизацию через смс.
Интересует часть касающаяся логики процесса на стороне сайта.

1. Как сделать чтобы, создание аккаунта юзера происходило после подтверждения смс? Т.е. просто создать аккаунт, а затем его активировать смс кодом не хочется, чтобы кучи аккаунтов не было. Да и если человек сразу не активирует, а потом через часа 2-3 попробует снова создать профиль, то регистрация будет выдавать ошибку о существовании данного номера в базе.
2. Как сделать чтобы код жил определенное время, скажем 1-3 минуты?
3. Как защитить себя от злоумышленников, которые захотят "сжечь" весь баланс путем отправки "холостых" смс?

Не знаю в какую сторону копать, делать сессии или писать в базу? если в базу, то как привязать к чему-либо, если аккаунт ещё не создан?

Или все же создавать аккаунт и потом его просто активировать, но все равно вопрос - как сделать эти смс коды временными (чтобы жили 1-3 минуты)?

Comment: *просто создать аккаунт, а затем его активировать смс кодом не хочется, чтобы кучи аккаунтов не было.* Установить срок жизни аккаунта без подтверждения. За час не подтверждён - считать невалидным. И удалять. *Как сделать чтобы код жил определенное время, скажем 1-3 минуты?* Установить срок актуальности кода. Если прошло более 3 минут - невалидный. И удалять. *"сжечь" весь баланс путем отправки "холостых" смс?* Фраза непонятна. Какой такой баланс?

Comment: *Как защитить себя от злоумышленников, которые захотят "сжечь" весь баланс путем отправки "холостых" смс?* Если Вы имеете в виду СВОЙ баланс на отправку СМС - то на повторный запрос должен быть свой тайм-аут. Как раз вот хорошо указаны границы *1-3 минуты* - повторный СМС отправлять не ранее чем через 1 минуту.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте форму регистрации с нужными полями. В ней кнопка "Получить код регистрации". По нажатию на кнопку записываете в сессию время нажатия и отправляете код регистрации на указанный номер телефона. Ждёте ввода пользователем кода регистрации в этой самой форме. При отправке заполненной формы проверяете, что код регистрации не устарел (те самые 3 минуты), что он правильный, и только после этого регистрируете пользователя на сайте.

Фразу `"сжечь" весь баланс путем отправки "холостых" смс` понимаю так - вы предполагаете, что на эту форму полезут боты и начнут заставлять сайт отправлять смс на самые разные номера.

Почитайте мой вопрос-ответ на эту тему: "[Как защитить от ботов форму регистрации на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)".

Comment: Спасибо, два комментария, противоположных).  Я на бумаге накидал вариант с работой в БД, слишком много проверок. Вопрос теоретический по ресурсам, что будет ресурсы сервера (хостинга) больше потреблять: одна сессия или 1-3 запроса в бд? не знаю насколько корректен вопрос, но ресурсы это важный пункт. А касательно каптчи, то надо будет искать решение без этого

Comment: Я думаю, вы переоцениваете влияние ресурсов на ваш проект. У вас будет 4000 регистраций в час? Если нет, не о чем переживать.

Comment: Без капчи - ищите, но мой вопрос-ответ по ссылке явно показал - нет иной возможности на данный момент противостоять умным ботам. Все эти honeypot не работают.

Answer (score 0):

По порядку:

> Как сделать чтобы, создание аккаунта юзера происходило после подтверждения смс? Т.е. просто создать аккаунт, а затем его активировать смс кодом не хочется, чтобы кучи аккаунтов не было.

Ну создайте табличку для неактивированных пользователей. И от туда будете переносить к основным (регистрировать вручную) только в функции успешного подтверждения.

> Да и если человек сразу не активирует, а потом через часа 2-3
>   попробует снова создать профиль, то регистрация будет выдавать ошибку
>   о существовании данного номера в базе.

Для этого мы разрешаем дубликаты логинов и номеров, уникальным ключом будет наш самый код в СМС (это надо гарантировать). При подтверждении все дубликаты из временной таблички - удаляем, а основную запись переносим к основным.

> Как сделать чтобы код жил определенное время, скажем 1-3 минуты?

Добавляем поле: время регистрации (когда была создана наша запись в БД), потом при подтверждении сравниваем текущее время и из бд, смотрим разницу.

> Как защитить себя от злоумышленников, которые захотят "сжечь" весь
>   баланс путем отправки "холостых" смс?

Обычно СМСки стоят копейки, кликать в туже рекапчу вечно, чтобы сжечь ваш баланс, злоумышленникам сразу надоест. Можно поставить лимит по IP.

> Не знаю в какую сторону копать, делать сессии или писать в базу? если
>   в базу, то как привязать к чему-либо, если аккаунт ещё не создан?

Однозначно в БД