# PHP. Wordpress. Спам

Tags: php, wordpress, email, спам

Всем привет. Думаю вы сможете мне помочь.
Взял сайт на обслуживание на вордпрессе. Кто там до меня работал не знаю, но сделано все через одно место(на мой взгляд, конечно, может так и правильно, но все же), отключили они в админке возможность устанавливать плагины, и еще кучу всяких возможностей стандартных закрыли.
Сейчас владельцам сайта через сайт приходит много различного спама(под этим они подразумевают рекламу разных компаний), то есть кто то вручную в поле для обратной связи вбивает сообщение, мол мы такие-то такие-то, предлагаем купить вам мазь от лишая, которая естественно владельцам сайта не нужна.
Как сделать фильтр от подобного рода спама?
И что вообще дальше делать с этим сайтом? Стоит ли заново все переделать?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то сообщения рассылают через форму, которая расположена на этом же сайте? Тогда прикрутить капчу форме...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: Стоит не браться за обслуживание того, чего совершено не знаешь. А то попадёшь к на операционный стол к плотнику, который взялся подшабашить на аппендицитах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Recaptcha) Для contact form 7 она уже встроена в модуль